# Very high cpu usage audio to audio call libjingle_peerconnection

Tags: ios, webrtc, libjingle

I'm using the `pod 'libjingle_peerconnection'` version (11177.2.0) at IOS.

The cpu runs at 103% (Iphone) when I'm making an audio to audio call on an and to an IOS device. It seems that it is an bug.

Because the PacerThread runs very high. So I was searching at that issue and more people have that problem:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=5506

At that topic the bug is marked as fixed. Nice:). But how can I get an updated library? I can't find anywhere an newer version.

Is it possible to build the libjingle_peerconnection for IOS myself with all the webrtc bug fixes included?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build it yourself using the following steps:

Checkout depot_tools using:

```
git clone https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/tools/depot_tools.git
export PATH=`pwd`/depot_tools:"$PATH"
```

Fetch webrtc source code using:

```
fetch --nohooks webrtc_ios  
gclient sync
```

Build your library using:

```
cd src
webrtc/build/ios/build_ios_libs.sh
```

use the following if you dont want the framework but the static library:

```
webrtc/build/ios/build_ios_libs.sh -b static_only
```

Source: https://webrtc.org/native-code/ios/